# Pivoting in Database View on Anylogic

Tags: sql, database, anylogic

I am currently trying to manipulate data on Anylogic using SQL queries with database views.Is it possible to use pivot/unpivot actions and/or cross apply on Anylogic? I am a beginner in SQL and was not able to get it done so far.

In the documentation I see only ordering, grouping, where, insert, update etc. as potential functions and clauses.

I would be very happy to hear some tips.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Atamert, can you please turn your general "any advice?" question to a specific "this is my situation, this is what I tried already, do you know how to achieve Y?" question? Happy to help but hard to reply with general statements. What do you mean by "pivot actions", for example? Generally, you can slice and dice data in any way with AnyLogic, like with SQL.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, to make it quick and precise I would like to use the action unpivot of SQL in database view of Anylogic. I am just trying to unpivot some specific columns in a table consisting of a few more columns into new rows and I just wanted to know, if there were any restrictions on Anylogic with database views with respect to basic unpivoting actions. Are you saying it should be possible?